# How set CSS grid to display unknown number of dynamic data

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm receiving an unknown number of images from a database, how do I set CSS grid to accommodate any number of images.

Example the first four images.

```
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 25px 25px;
   grid-template-colunms: 25px 25px;
}
```

how can I make all the images to follow a certain rule.

Comment: What does your layout look like or whats the output of your code? Are all the images different sizes or are they fixed width and height? It would be helpful if you provided more info

Comment: The layout: Two landscape images with the same size on in a row, then the rest follow below in the same order. All the images are the same size, same height and weight @crazymatt

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer and it works for me well.

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "a a";
    grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Fix your typos. should be `grid-template-areas` and `.grid-container`